# C# AzureMaps page doesn't show the map when moving to MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-maps

I have a html page of AzureMaps on [github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/main/Samples/Tutorials/Interactive%20Search/Interactive%20Search%20Quickstart.html). I run directly the html file by Chrome and it works. But when I move it to MVC application, it doesn't show the map.

I don't know what I'm missing when I come to MVC. It just displays as below. Left is html run directly by Chrome and it works. Right is page from Index.cshtml and it doesn't show the map, even no error in console so I have no idea what goes wrong.

[image]

This [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/quick-demo-map-app) refers to the Github link above.

Do you have any idea on this?

Thanks very much.

I just copy everything from the .html file to the Index.cshtml page.

My Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Interactive Search Quickstart - Azure Maps Web SDK Samples</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="This tutorial shows how to create an interactive search experience." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Microsoft maps, map, gis, API, SDK, services, module, tutorials, search, point of interest, POI" />
    <meta name="author" content="Microsoft Azure Maps" />
    <meta name="screenshot" content="screenshot.jpg" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add a reference to the Azure Maps Services Module JavaScript file. -->
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/service/2/atlas-service.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var map, datasource, client, popup, searchInput, resultsPanel, searchInputLength, centerMapOnResults;

        //The minimum number of characters needed in the search input before a search is performed.
        var minSearchInputLength = 3;

        //The number of ms between key strokes to wait before performing a search.
        var keyStrokeDelay = 150;

        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [-118.270293, 34.039737],
                zoom: 14,
                view: 'Auto',

                //Add authentication details for connecting to Azure Maps.
                authOptions: {
                    ////Use Azure Active Directory authentication.
                    //authType: 'anonymous',
                    //clientId: 'e6b6ab59-eb5d-4d25-aa57-581135b927f0', //Your Azure Maps client id for accessing your Azure Maps account.
                    //getToken: function (resolve, reject, map) {
                    //    //URL to your authentication service that retrieves an Azure Active Directory Token.
                    //    var tokenServiceUrl = "https://samples.azuremaps.com/api/GetAzureMapsToken";

                    //    fetch(tokenServiceUrl).then(r => r.text()).then(token => resolve(token));
                    //}

                    //Alternatively, use an Azure Maps key. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: 'W*******U'
                }
            });

            //Store a reference to the Search Info Panel.
            resultsPanel = document.getElementById("results-panel");

            //Add key up event to the search box.
            searchInput = document.getElementById("search-input");
            searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", searchInputKeyup);

            //Create a popup which we can reuse for each result.
            popup = new atlas.Popup();

            //Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {

                //Add the zoom control to the map.
                map.controls.add(new atlas.control.ZoomControl(), {
                    position: 'top-right'
                });

                //Create a data source and add it to the map.
                datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add(datasource);

                //Add a layer for rendering the results.
                var searchLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                    iconOptions: {
                        image: 'pin-round-darkblue',
                        anchor: 'center',
                        allowOverlap: true
                    }
                });
                map.layers.add(searchLayer);

                //Add a click event to the search layer and show a popup when a result is clicked.
                map.events.add("click", searchLayer, function (e) {
                    //Make sure the event occurred on a shape feature.
                    if (e.shapes && e.shapes.length > 0) {
                        showPopup(e.shapes[0]);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        function searchInputKeyup(e) {
            centerMapOnResults = false;
            if (searchInput.value.length >= minSearchInputLength) {
                if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                    centerMapOnResults = true;
                }
                //Wait 100ms and see if the input length is unchanged before performing a search.
                //This will reduce the number of queries being made on each character typed.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (searchInputLength == searchInput.value.length) {
                        search();
                    }
                }, keyStrokeDelay);
            } else {
                resultsPanel.innerHTML = '';
            }
            searchInputLength = searchInput.value.length;
        }
        function search() {
            //Remove any previous results from the map.
            datasource.clear();
            popup.close();
            resultsPanel.innerHTML = '';

            //Use MapControlCredential to share authentication between a map control and the service module.
            var pipeline = atlas.service.MapsURL.newPipeline(new atlas.service.MapControlCredential(map));

            //Construct the SearchURL object
            var searchURL = new atlas.service.SearchURL(pipeline);

            var query = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
            searchURL.searchPOI(atlas.service.Aborter.timeout(10000), query, {
                lon: map.getCamera().center[0],
                lat: map.getCamera().center[1],
                maxFuzzyLevel: 4,
                view: 'Auto'
            }).then((results) => {

                //Extract GeoJSON feature collection from the response and add it to the datasource
                var data = results.geojson.getFeatures();
                datasource.add(data);

                if (centerMapOnResults) {
                    map.setCamera({
                        bounds: data.bbox
                    });
                }
                console.log(data);
                //Create the HTML for the results list.
                var html = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
                    var r = data.features[i];
                    html.push('<li onclick="itemClicked(\'', r.id, '\')" onmouseover="itemHovered(\'', r.id, '\')">')
                    html.push('<div class="title">');
                    if (r.properties.poi && r.properties.poi.name) {
                        html.push(r.properties.poi.name);
                    } else {
                        html.push(r.properties.address.freeformAddress);
                    }
                    html.push('</div><div class="info">', r.properties.type, ': ', r.properties.address.freeformAddress, '</div>');
                    if (r.properties.poi) {
                        if (r.properties.phone) {
                            html.push('<div class="info">phone: ', r.properties.poi.phone, '</div>');
                        }
                        if (r.properties.poi.url) {
                            html.push('<div class="info"><a href="http://', r.properties.poi.url, '">http://', r.properties.poi.url, '</a></div>');
                        }
                    }
                    html.push('</li>');
                    resultsPanel.innerHTML = html.join('');
                }

            });
        }
        function itemHovered(id) {
            //Show a popup when hovering an item in the result list.
            var shape = datasource.getShapeById(id);
            showPopup(shape);
        }
        function itemClicked(id) {
            //Center the map over the clicked item from the result list.
            var shape = datasource.getShapeById(id);
            map.setCamera({
                center: shape.getCoordinates(),
                zoom: 17
            });
        }
        function showPopup(shape) {
            var properties = shape.getProperties();
            //Create the HTML content of the POI to show in the popup.
            var html = ['<div class="poi-box">'];
            //Add a title section for the popup.
            html.push('<div class="poi-title-box"><b>');

            if (properties.poi && properties.poi.name) {
                html.push(properties.poi.name);
            } else {
                html.push(properties.address.freeformAddress);
            }
            html.push('</b></div>');
            //Create a container for the body of the content of the popup.
            html.push('<div class="poi-content-box">');
            html.push('<div class="info location">', properties.address.freeformAddress, '</div>');
            if (properties.poi) {
                if (properties.poi.phone) {
                    html.push('<div class="info phone">', properties.phone, '</div>');
                }
                if (properties.poi.url) {
                    html.push('<div><a class="info website" href="http://', properties.poi.url, '">http://', properties.poi.url, '</a></div>');
                }
            }
            html.push('</div></div>');
            popup.setOptions({
                position: shape.getCoordinates(),
                content: html.join('')
            });
            popup.open(map);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: segoeui;
        }

        #myMap {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #search {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 400px;
            box-shadow: 0px 24px 74px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .32);
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

            #search > .search-input-box {
                background: #fff;
                height: 72px;
                width: 100%;
            }

                #search > .search-input-box > .search-input-group {
                    position: relative;
                    top: 20px;
                    left: 20px;
                    width: 358px;
                    height: 30px;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
                }

                    #search > .search-input-box > .search-input-group > .search-icon {
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                        background-size: 20px 20px;
                        width: 30px;
                        height: 30px;
                        background-position: center;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg id='Layer_1' data-name='Layer 1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3E%3Ctitle%3E-%3C/title%3E%3Cpath d='M10.5,0a5.4457,5.4457,0,0,1,2.7734.75A5.6134,5.6134,0,0,1,15.25,2.7266a5.5224,5.5224,0,0,1,.5547,4.2344A5.4147,5.4147,0,0,1,15.25,8.2734,5.6134,5.6134,0,0,1,13.2734,10.25a5.5014,5.5014,0,0,1-4.6445.4219,5.6256,5.6256,0,0,1-1.6445-.9453L.8516,15.8516A.4807.4807,0,0,1,.5,16a.4823.4823,0,0,1-.3516-.1484.4905.4905,0,0,1,0-.7031l6.125-6.1328a5.6194,5.6194,0,0,1-.9453-1.6445A5.39,5.39,0,0,1,5,5.5a5.4457,5.4457,0,0,1,.75-2.7734A5.6134,5.6134,0,0,1,7.7266.75,5.4457,5.4457,0,0,1,10.5,0Zm0,10a4.347,4.347,0,0,0,1.75-.3555A4.5254,4.5254,0,0,0,14.6445,7.25,4.347,4.347,0,0,0,15,5.5a4.347,4.347,0,0,0-.3555-1.75A4.5254,4.5254,0,0,0,12.25,1.3555a4.4854,4.4854,0,0,0-3.5,0A4.5254,4.5254,0,0,0,6.3555,3.75a4.4854,4.4854,0,0,0,0,3.5A4.5254,4.5254,0,0,0,8.75,9.6445,4.3487,4.3487,0,0,0,10.5,10Z' fill='%234b4b4b'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
                    }

                    #search > .search-input-box > .search-input-group > input {
                        display: inline-block;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0px;
                        left: 30px;
                        width: calc(100% - 40px);
                        height: 100%;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0 5px;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        border: 0px;
                    }

                        #search > .search-input-box > .search-input-group > input:focus {
                            outline: none;
                        }

        #results-panel {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            list-style: none;
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: calc(100vh - 119px);
        }

            #results-panel > li {
                border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
                padding: 10px 20px;
            }

                #results-panel > li:hover {
                    background-color: #f1f2f2;
                    cursor: pointer;
                }

                #results-panel > li > .title {
                    font-family: segoeui-b;
                    line-height: 14pt;
                    width: 100%;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }

                #results-panel > li > .info {
                    width: 100%;
                    line-height: 14pt;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    text-overflow: ellipsis;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }

        .poi-box {
            max-width: 200px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .poi-title-box {
            background-color: #153C64;
            width: calc(100% - 16px);
            height: 23px;
            padding: 8px;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 12px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
            font-family: segoeui-b;
        }

        .poi-content-box {
            width: calc(100% - 16px);
            height: calc(100% - 39px);
            padding: 8px;
        }

            .poi-content-box .info {
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: block;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: left;
                padding-left: 15px;
                background-size: 10px 10px;
                width: calc(100% - 15px);
            }

        .info .phone {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBpZD0iTGF5ZXJfMSIgZGF0YS1uYW1lPSJMYXllciAxIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNS45NzQ2IDI2Ij48dGl0bGU+cG9pPC90aXRsZT48cGF0aCBkPSJNMjAuMzkxNCwxNS4zOTk0YTIuODE0MSwyLjgxNDEsMCwwLDEsMS4wNzIyLjIwOTUsMi43MjQzLDIuNzI0MywwLDAsMSwuOTA3My42MDNsMi43OTE2LDIuNzkzYTIuNzI1OCwyLjcyNTgsMCwwLDEsLjYwMjcuOTA3NywyLjg1MjksMi44NTI5LDAsMCwxLDAsMi4xNDU1LDIuNzI1OCwyLjcyNTgsMCwwLDEtLjYwMjcuOTA3N3EtLjcyMzMuNzM2My0xLjMyLDEuMzAxM2E3LjQwNDMsNy40MDQzLDAsMCwxLTEuMjMwOC45NTIxLDUuMDk1LDUuMDk1LDAsMCwxLTEuNDA4NS41ODRBNy42NjM4LDcuNjYzOCwwLDAsMSwxOS4zMzgyLDI2YTExLjQ3NywxMS40NzcsMCwwLDEtMy4yNjExLS40OTUxLDE4LjA4ODIsMTguMDg4MiwwLDAsMS0zLjMzMDktMS4zNzExLDIzLjg4LDIzLjg4LDAsMCwxLTMuMjQ4NC0yLjA4MkEyOC4xNTgsMjguMTU4LDAsMCwxLDYuNDksMTkuNDE3NSwyOC44OTc1LDI4Ljg5NzUsMCwwLDEsMy44ODI5LDE2LjM5NmEyMy42NzQ3LDIzLjY3NDcsMCwwLDEtMi4wNTU2LTMuMjVBMTguMjMyNywxOC4yMzI3LDAsMCwxLC40ODIyLDkuODM4OSwxMS4zODY0LDExLjM4NjQsMCwwLDEsMCw2LjY0LDcuNTk1Niw3LjU5NTYsMCwwLDEsLjE5NjcsNC43OCw1LjIxLDUuMjEsMCwwLDEsLjc4LDMuMzcwNmE3LjA3NSw3LjA3NSwwLDAsMSwuOTUxNy0xLjIzMTRxLjU2NDctLjU5LDEuMzAwNi0xLjMxNEEyLjgyNywyLjgyNywwLDAsMSwzLjkzMzYuMjE1OGEyLjc4NzIsMi43ODcyLDAsMCwxLDIuMTUwOCwwLDIuODA3OSwyLjgwNzksMCwwLDEsLjkwNzMuNjA5NGwyLjc5MTYsMi43OTNhMi43MjU4LDIuNzI1OCwwLDAsMSwuNjAyNy45MDc3LDIuODE3OSwyLjgxNzksMCwwLDEsLjIwOTQsMS4wNzI4LDIuNDc4LDIuNDc4LDAsMCwxLS4xOS45OTY2LDMuNjAxNiwzLjYwMTYsMCwwLDEtLjQ2OTUuNzkzNSw0LjY5NzksNC42OTc5LDAsMCwxLS42MTU0LjY0NzVxLS4zMzYzLjI5Mi0uNjE1NC41NzEzYTMuNzMyNCwzLjczMjQsMCwwLDAtLjQ2OTUuNTY0OSwxLjA4OTQsMS4wODk0LDAsMCwwLS4xOS42MTU3LDEuMTI1MiwxLjEyNTIsMCwwLDAsLjM0MjYuODI1Mmw2Ljk5MTcsNi45OTUxYTEuMTI0MSwxLjEyNDEsMCwwLDAsLjgyNDguMzQyOCwxLjA4ODEsMS4wODgxLDAsMCwwLC42MTU0LS4xOSwzLjczMTMsMy43MzEzLDAsMCwwLC41NjQ3LS40N3EuMjc5Mi0uMjc5My41NzEtLjYxNTdhNC42OTc1LDQuNjk3NSwwLDAsMSwuNjQ3MS0uNjE1NywzLjU5OTEsMy41OTkxLDAsMCwxLC43OTMxLS40NywyLjQ3NDcsMi40NzQ3LDAsMCwxLC45OTYxLS4xOU0xOS4zMzgyLDI0LjM3NWE1Ljc5NDIsNS43OTQyLDAsMCwwLDEuNTI5LS4xNzE0LDMuOTQ3OCwzLjk0NzgsMCwwLDAsMS4xMS0uNDk1MSw1LjczNDEsNS43MzQxLDAsMCwwLC45NjQ0LS44MDYycS40Njk1LS40ODI0LDEuMDc4Ni0xLjA5MThhMS4xMjUyLDEuMTI1MiwwLDAsMCwuMzQyNi0uODI1MiwxLjEwNDUsMS4xMDQ1LDAsMCwwLS4xODQtLjU0LDQuNzY0OSw0Ljc2NDksMCwwLDAtLjQ3NTgtLjY1MzhxLS4yOTE5LS4zNDI4LS42NTM1LS43MDQ2dC0uNzEwNi0uNjg1NXEtLjM0OS0uMzIzNy0uNjQ3MS0uNTk2N3QtLjQ2MzItLjQzOGExLjEzODksMS4xMzg5LDAsMCwwLS44Mzc1LS4zNDI4LDEuMDU4NywxLjA1ODcsMCwwLDAtLjYwOTEuMTksMy45MTY4LDMuOTE2OCwwLDAsMC0uNTU4My40N3EtLjI3OTIuMjc5My0uNTc3NC42MTU3YTUuMDAyNiw1LjAwMjYsMCwwLDEtLjY1MzUuNjE1NywzLjU5OTEsMy41OTkxLDAsMCwxLS43OTMxLjQ3LDIuNDc0NywyLjQ3NDcsMCwwLDEtLjk5NjEuMTksMi44MTQxLDIuODE0MSwwLDAsMS0xLjA3MjItLjIwOTUsMi43MjQzLDIuNzI0MywwLDAsMS0uOTA3My0uNjAzTDcuMjMyOCwxMS43Njg2YTIuNzI1OCwyLjcyNTgsMCwwLDEtLjYwMjctLjkwNzcsMi44MTc5LDIuODE3OSwwLDAsMS0uMjA5NC0xLjA3MjgsMi40NzgsMi40NzgsMCwwLDEsLjE5LS45OTY2LDMuNjAxNiwzLjYwMTYsMCwwLDEsLjQ2OTUtLjc5MzUsNS4wMDMsNS4wMDMsMCwwLDEsLjYxNTQtLjY1MzhxLjMzNjMtLjI5ODMuNjE1NC0uNTc3NmEzLjkxNzgsMy45MTc4LDAsMCwwLC40Njk1LS41NTg2LDEuMDYsMS4wNiwwLDAsMCwuMTktLjYwOTQsMS4xNCwxLjE0LDAsMCwwLS4zNDI2LS44Mzc5cS0uMTY1LS4xNjUtLjQzNzgtLjQ2MzRUNy41OTQ0LDMuNjVxLS4zMjM2LS4zNDkxLS42ODUyLS43MTA5VDYuMjA1LDIuMjg1MmE0Ljc2MjcsNC43NjI3LDAsMCwwLS42NTM1LS40NzYxLDEuMTAzMiwxLjEwMzIsMCwwLDAtLjUzOTMtLjE4NDEsMS4xMjQxLDEuMTI0MSwwLDAsMC0uODI0OC4zNDI4cS0uNjA5MS42MDk0LTEuMDg0OSwxLjA3OTFhNi40NjgzLDYuNDY4MywwLDAsMC0uODEyMS45NjQ4LDMuNzUsMy43NSwwLDAsMC0uNTA3NiwxLjExMDhBNS43NDQyLDUuNzQ0MiwwLDAsMCwxLjYxMTUsNi42NGE5Ljk4MzQsOS45ODM0LDAsMCwwLC40NjMyLDIuOTMyNiwxNi41LDE2LjUsMCwwLDAsMS4yODE2LDMuMDIxNSwyMy4wMTM3LDIzLjAxMzcsMCwwLDAsMS45MzUxLDIuOTc3MSwyNi41MjI5LDI2LjUyMjksMCwwLDAsMi40MzYzLDIuNzczOSwyNy4yODMyLDI3LjI4MzIsMCwwLDAsMi43ODUzLDIuNDEyMSwyMi45ODcsMjIuOTg3LDAsMCwwLDIuOTY5MywxLjkxMDYsMTYuMzY2MSwxNi4zNjYxLDAsMCwwLDIuOTk0NiwxLjI1NjhBOS44ODEsOS44ODEsMCwwLDAsMTkuMzM4MiwyNC4zNzVaIiBmaWxsPSIjNjY2NzY3Ii8+PC9zdmc+");
        }

        .info .website {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
        }

        .info .location {
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap"></div>

    <div id="search">
        <div class="search-input-box">
            <div class="search-input-group">
                <div class="search-icon" type="button"></div>
                <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="results-panel"></ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

cshtml files are generally meant to contain a subset of HTML elements that go into a page, but you are pasting in the code for a full HTML page, thus putting an HTML page element within another one which generally doesn't go well. The root cause of the issue you are seeing is that the original example modifies the  css of the body and html page to stretch to full width/height, and the map is set to take up 100% of these. However, when rendered via MVC, the map is not in the root body tag, but within the `main` tag of the generated page which has CSS that ignores percentage-based widths/heights.

A simple fix so you can see the map is to add the following CSS:

```
main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 150px);
}
```

This gives the `main` element of the page a size that the map can then fill up. Alternatively, you can give the maps div element a fixed size in pixels.